# How does filter know what the condition is if it is supposed to just return a boolean value?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I am using SwiftUI and some live filtering of CoreData to display `Views` based on a date selection. The `filter` is happening in a `ForEach` and works probably here:

```
ForEach(self.bookings.filter {
     self.selectedDate.isEmpty ? true : $0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)
}, id: \.self) { booking in
    NavigationLink(destination: BookingDetail(theBooking: booking)) {
        HStack {
                ...
    }}
```

What I'm doing in the `filer { ... }` code here is first checking to see if the `selectedDate` string is empty, if it is, returning true displays all records in `bookings`. If it is not empty (meaning a user has selected a date), then `bookings` that match the selected date are displayed. Checking for this match is a string comparison where `toString` is an extension of the Date() method as a `dateFormatter`

This works. But I don't understand why, and it's keeping me from building upon it.

#### First part of question

How does this code know to get only the `booking` values if this: `$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)` is just returning a boolean value? It must also return an array right? (or a copy / reference of one)

So based on that, I wanted to add more functionality so that if the user selected a date where there were no matches, all of the `bookings` are displayed. Currently, if a date is selected that has no booking match, no bookings are displayed.

I attempted to add a nested ternary operator to achieve this but it's not working as I expect it to, and I cannot figure out why.

```
ForEach(self.bookings.filter {
    self.selectedDate.isEmpty ? true : $0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate) ? true : !$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)
}
```

To me, this filter is should be "asking"

- If the selected date is empty, return true (displaying all bookings)
- If the selected date is not empty, check to see if there is a `booking` match for the selected date
- If there is a match, display the matched bookings
- If there is a not a match, display all of the bookings that don't match `selectedDate` (all of the bookings).

However this code just displays all of the bookings constantly regardless of `selectedDates` value.

Shouldn't the first occurrence of `$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)` be evaualated as an `if` then go on to evaluate `!$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)` if it's false, and this will return the list of bookings that does not "match" `selectedDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` iterates over all elements of the `Array` it is called on, executes the same closure for each element and returns a new array, which only contains the elements, for which the closure returned `true`.

> How does this code know to get only the booking values if this: $0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate) is just returning a boolean value? It must also return an array right? (or a copy / reference of one)

As explained above, the condition in that closure is executed for each element of `bookings` and `filter` returns a new `Array`, which contains only the elements for which the closure returned `true`.

Your second expression with the nested ternary expression is actually equivalent to your first expression without the nested ternary expression. If you look at it more closely,
`$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate) ? true : !$0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate)`, the expression after the `:` is simply the negated version of the condition of your ternary expression. So basically, this means `a ? true : !a`, which is equivalent to `a` itself.

If you want to achieve

> So based on that, I wanted to add more functionality so that if the user selected a date where there were no matches, all of the bookings are displayed.

, I would suggest saving the result of your original `filter` into a local variable, then checking whether this array is empty, if not, call `ForEach` on the filtered array, otherwise call it on `bookings`.

```
let bookingsForSelectedDate = self.bookings.filter { self.selectedDate.isEmpty ? true : $0.startdate!.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd").contains(selectedDate) }
let matchingOrAllBookings = !bookingsForSelectedDate.isEmpty ? bookingsForSelectedDate : self.bookings
ForEach(matchingOrAllBookings, id: \.self) { booking in
    NavigationLink(destination: BookingDetail(theBooking: booking)) {
        HStack {
                ...
    }}
```